# Can't access Ms-Access DB 2013.

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2013

I cannot access my DB on MS Access when I enter data when I click on save, the MsgBox shows that says that could not find file path directory. Do you know what am I doing wrong and why my DB is not connecting as expected?

```
public partial class signup : Form
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪ amsid.accdb");

    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    public signup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {    
            ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into Signup values(@Username,@Password,@Email,@Admin_Code)", con);
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = password.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = email.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Admin_Code", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = admincode.Text.ToString();

            con.Open();
            ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly state the path of your `.accdb` file and it should fix your issue.